# How to use print format to make box around text java?

Tags: java, printf

```
public static void printBox(Scanner in, int length) {
    
    int spacesNeeded = 0;
    System.out.print("+"); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= length + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    } 
    
    System.out.print("+");    
    System.out.println();
        
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("| " + in.nextLine() + " |");
    } 
    
    System.out.print("+");
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= length + 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    
    System.out.print("+");    
    System.out.println();
    
}
```

Above code makes a box like this:

```
+--------------+
| This is some |
| text here. |
+--------------+
```

I need to find a better way to format this box and make the lines even with maybe a System.printf? or a better for loop process.

End products needs to be:

```
+--------------+
| This is some |
| text here.   |
+--------------+
```

Comment: A better way would be to get all the input lines and store them. Then find the maximum length of line so that you will know when you should print **|**

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by writing a routine to get the maximum length of a number of `String`(s); something like

```
private static int getMaxLength(String... strings) {
    int len = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String str : strings) {
        len = Math.max(str.length(), len);
    }
    return len;
}
```

and methods to pad and and fill `String`(s). Padding can be done with something like

```
private static String padString(String str, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    return sb.append(fill(' ', len - str.length())).toString();
}
```

Then you fill a `String` with `len` repeats of character `ch`(s) like

```
private static String fill(char ch, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, `printBox` is determining the length of the longest `String`. Building a top (and bottom line) then iterating the `String`(s) performing padding (if needed) on the `String`(s) and then using formatted output - `| str |` like

```
public static void printBox(String... strings) {
    int maxBoxWidth = getMaxLength(strings);
    String line = "+" + fill('-', maxBoxWidth + 2) + "+";
    System.out.println(line);
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.printf("| %s |%n", padString(str, maxBoxWidth));
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Then (for example)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printBox("Thie is some", "text here.");
}
```

Output is

```
+--------------+
| Thie is some |
| text here.   |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're *certain* the lines won't be too long, you can use this for your inner-most loop:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.nextLine();
    int spaces = length - s.length();
    System.out.print("| " + s);
    while (spaces-- > 0)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.println(" |");
}
```

This gives you output like:

```
+----------------------+
| hello there          |
| my name is pax       |
+----------------------+
```

for a length of `20` and a scanner providing those lines.

In that case, if the lines are longer than expected, you'll see something like:

```
+----------------------+
| hello there          |
| my name is pax       |
| This line is way too long |
+----------------------+
```

so, if that's possible, you may want to scan in all the lines up front (into a collection of some sort) keeping track of the maximum length as you go. Then use *that* length to decide how to print it out.

In other words, something like this, also refactoring out the code for the top and bottom edges since this is good practice:

```
public static void topBottom (int length) {
    System.out.print("+"); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= length + 1; i++)
        System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println("+");    
}

public static void printBox(Scanner in, int length) {
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String s = in.nextLine();
        if (s.length() > length)
            length = s.length();
        lines.add(s);
    }

    topBottom(length);
    for (String s: lines) {
        int spaces = length - s.length();
        System.out.print("| " + s);
        while (spaces-- > 0)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(" |");
    }
    topBottom(length);
}
```

which adapts to the longest line:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| hello there                                                 |
| my name is pax                                              |
| and this is a very long line designed to test the functions |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If your length is fix then you can use below code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

String s;
while (in.hasNext()) {
    s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("| " + s + StringUtils.repeat(" ", length - s.length()) + " |");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by storing the strings and finding the maximum width among all sentences (`maxLength`) and then by printing them.

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int maxLength=0;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String s="";
while (in.hasNext()) {
    s=in.nextLine();
    list.add(s);
    if(maxLength<s.length())
     maxLength=s.length();
} 

System.out.print("+");
for (int i = 0; i <= maxLength+1 ; i++) {
    System.out.print("-");
} 
 System.out.println("+");
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
     System.out.print("| ");
     s=list.get(i);
     System.out.print(s);

    for(int k=s.length();k<=maxLength;k++)
        System.out.print(" ");

    System.out.println("|");

}
System.out.print("+");
for (int i = 0; i <= maxLength+1 ; i++) {
    System.out.print("-");
} 
 System.out.println("+");
```

this will product output as

```
+--------------+
| hello        |
| good morning |
| have a       |
| nice day     |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make things dynamic, instead of hardcoded values.

-> take input from user beforehand

->  scan the inputs and find maxlength of the word in input

-> adjust spacing according to the max wordlength

Here is a program that works fine:-

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = 10;
        int spacesNeeded = 0;
        int size = 0;
        System.out.println("How many inputs?");
        size = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        String[] inputs = new String[size];
        System.out.println("Enter words");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            inputs[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.print("+");

        int maxsize = 0;

        for (String s : inputs) {
            if (s.length() > maxsize) {
                maxsize = s.length();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxsize + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
            System.out.print("| " + inputs[j]);

            for (int i = inputs[j].length(); i <= maxsize; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(" |");
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.print("+");

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxsize + 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }

        System.out.print("+");
        System.out.println();
        in.close();
    }
```

Output:-

```
+-------------------+
| helodejfnsdjfnsdf  |
| dfdf               |
| dfdf               |
| sdfsdf             |
+-------------------+
```